# Is it possible to bounce on this aerial checkpoint?

Tags: trackmania-forever

Is it possible to bounce on this aerial checkpoint and land on the middle landing lane, as the red lines show in the screenshot below?

[image]

I want to make sure that the only reachable landing lane in the one at the bottom left (and  the car has to go through the aerial checkpoint):

[image]

You can download the track [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sf4ulbzavu31xxz/clause4centered_aerial-lower_extended_left.Challenge.Gbx?dl=0).

Comment: Have you tried testing it? You know you can test out maps you create, right?

Comment: @memescientist I have tried it exhaustively, I could bounce to some extent but not enough to reach the middle landing lane (I could do around 50-60% of the gap between the aerial checkpoint and the middle landing lane). I wonder whether anyone tried to quantify the maximum bounce achievable on aerial checkpoints.

Comment: Unless you're the best player in the world, your own testing isn't going to cut it here, a safer bet would be to just add checkpoints to ensure the player can't use such a jump as a shortcut.

Comment: I would say that it pretty much depends on the heights. Most likely the path is more steerable than you think, but maintaining enough speed to cross the gap after hitting the CP in midair looks tricky at the very least. However, as it might be possible to just skip the CP altogether and come for it later, I would say that it's much safer to just add (aerial) CPs to all lanes.